# using LEFT OUTER JOIN to retrieve data

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to be able to match a field in Table1 and echo data from Table1 along with the matching fields in Table2. I tried the below but did not work.

Example:

[image]

I want to echo data in this order: `items(Table1), category(Table1), preice(Table2), buyer(Table1)`

```
$serchRslt = "fr732001";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Table1.items, Table1.category, Table1.buyer, Table2.price, Table2.stocks Table2 
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.item = Table1.items FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.items  = '".$serchRslt."'");

while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $line["items"];
echo $line["category"];
echo $line["price"];
echo $line["buyer"];
}
```

Expected result: `fr732001 fruits 3.20 AS1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query should be

```
SELECT Table1.items, 
Table1.category, 
Table1.buyer, 
Table2.price, 
Table2.stocks 
from Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.item = Table1.items 
WHERE Table1.items  = 'fr732001';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Sql Syntax looks a bit wonky. Try:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.items, 
  Table1.category, 
  Table1.buyer, 
  Table2.price,  
  Table2.stocks 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.item = Table1.items
WHERE Table1.items  = $...
```